# May someone help me why my console returns only 0 when i input this data in console?

Tags: javascript

This is exercise from Softuni book "Основи на програмирането с JavaScript" 5.2 loop

```js
function divide(args) {
 let n = Number(args[0]);

 let divideByTwo = 0; 
 let divideByThree = 0; 
 let divideByFour = 0; 

 for (let i = 1; i <= n ; i++) {
  let numbers = Number(args[i])
  if(numbers % 2 === 0 ){
   divideByTwo++;
  }
  
  if (numbers % 3 === 0) {
   divideByThree++;
  }

  if (numbers % 4 === 0 ) {
   divideByFour++;
  }
 }
 let p1 = (divideByTwo / n) * 100;
 let p2 = (divideByThree / n) * 100;
 let p3 = (divideByFour / n) * 100;

 console.log(`P1: ${divideByTwo.toFixed(2)}% `);
 console.log(`P2: ${divideByThree.toFixed(2)}% `);
 console.log(`P3: ${divideByFour.toFixed(2)}%`);
}

divide(10 , 680 , 2 , 600 , 200 , 800 , 799 , 199 , 46 , 128 , 65)
```

Comment: You're passing a bunch of arguments, but with `divide(args) {` you're only using the first argument. Use `...args` instead (or `arguments`, not recommended). Also change the ``P1: ${divideByTwo.``s to ``P1: ${p1.`` - then your code works

Comment: Thank you ! At least 2 days I am trying to figure out what i am doing wrong :(